# Jetty OJDBC java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jetty, ojdbc

Could you help me, please. I have war file from Welogic. And I need to start it at jetty. My jetty-env.xml:

```
    <New id="dataSource" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg>jdbc/rtnDS</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
               <!-- <Set name="DriverType">thin</Set>-->
                <Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.20.10.221:1521:rtn.rtn.taganka</Set>
                <Set name="User">RTN_PROD17_F5</Set>
                <Set name="Password">*******</Set>
                <Set name="connectionCachingEnabled">true</Set>
                <Set name="connectionCacheProperties">
                    <New class="java.util.Properties">
                        <Call name="setProperty">
                            <Arg>MinLimit</Arg>
                            <Arg>5</Arg>
                        </Call>
                    </New>
                </Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
```

But i have an error when jetty is starting
[WARNING] Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@5399f6c5{/,file:///C:/Users/Viachaslau/IdeaProjects/JobsLocal/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:///C:/Users/Viachaslau/IdeaProjects/JobsLocal/src/main/webapp/}
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: My jetty-env.xml ignores any datasources. When I write wrong URL  or User,  or I comment datasources, exception is the same

Comment: Please edit your question and include the entire stacktrace. There's not enough information to work with as the question currently stands.